# Specify loader configuration from webpack config file in request

Tags: javascript, webpack

### Question

Is possible to specify loader from webpack config file in request by something like alias?
I'm looking for implementation of this idea:

**webpack config**

```
loaders: [
    {   // loaderA - default
        test: /\.js/,
        loaders: ['loader-a1', 'loader-a2'] 
    },

    {   // loaderB - I want to enable this in require
        test: /\.js/,
        loaders: ['loader-b1', 'loader-b2'] 
    }
]
```

**usage**

default - will use `['loader-a1', 'loader-a2']`

```
require('./module');
```

custom - will use `['loader-b1', 'loader-b2']`: disable `loaderA` and enable `loaderB`

```
require('!loaderB!./module');
```

---

### Known solution

My example can be written like this (but is not and answer for me):

**weback config**

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js/,
        loaders: ['loader-a1', 'loader-a2'] 
    }
]
```

**usage**

default

```
require('./module');
```

custom

```
require('!loader-b1!loader-b2!./module');
```

---

### Motivation

**1.** Creating loaders chain in require can be long and DRY.
This require can sometimes can be really to long

```
require('!loader-b1!loader-b2!loader-b3!loader-b4!./module');
```

**2.** It's hard to use variables in require loaders

Creating variables in `webpack.config.js` can easily handle different use case of loaders. It's awful to crate the same case in inline `require`

**weback config**

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js/,
        loaders: [
            `loader-a1?${JSON.stringify({
                sourceMap: DEBUG,
                minimize: !DEBUG
             })}`, 
            `loader-a2?${JSON.stringify({
                sourceMap: DEBUG,
                minimize: !DEBUG
             })}`
        ] 
    }
]
```

**usage**

default - using variables in loaders

```
require('./module');
```

custom - using variables in loaders - it looks so awful and you have to expose building variable `DEBUG`

```
require(`!loader-b1?${JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: DEBUG, minimize: !DEBUG })}!loader-b2?${JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: DEBUG, minimize: !DEBUG })}!./module`);
```

### Tip

I used word **alias**.

Comment: You could have custom extension regex. `/\.a.js$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for this is [resolveLoader.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader)

**webpack config**

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {   // loaderA - default
            test: /\.js/,
            loaders: ['loader-a1', 'loader-a2'] 
        }
    ]
},
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        loaderB: ['loader-b1', 'loader-b2'] // I want to enable this in require
    }
}
```

**usage**

default - will use ['loader-a1', 'loader-a2']

```
require('./module');
```

custom - will use ['loader-b1', 'loader-b2']: disable loaderA and enable loaderB

```
require('!loaderB!./module');
```

Answer (score 2):

It may not be *the answer you are looking for*, but you could decorate the JavaScript file extensions and have a loader definition for each

```
loaders: [
{   // loaderA - default
    test: /\(.a)?.js/,
    loaders: ['loader-a1', 'loader-a2'] 
},

{   // loaderB - I want to enable this in require
    test: /\.b.js/,
    loaders: ['loader-b1', 'loader-b2'] 
}
]
```

You would want to make one of the extensions optional so that it can fall back to external libraries or other JS files.

You could also use the `includes` property which will take a regex and tell webpack to only look for files (you want to run with loaderA) in a specific folder path.

Comment: Yes, it can be done that way. There is some caveat of this solution: when I want to use `loaderB` on external files (for example from node_modules) I must create file between  with extension `.b.js` containing only `require('external_module')`.