# Webpack 2+: How to apply different loaders for files with same extension?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Here's my use-case: Most svgs should be inlined. So I setup a rule like this:

```
{test: /\.svg$/, use: "svg-inline-loader"},
```

In some instances I just want the url of an svg rather than inlining it.
In webpack 1.x I required them like this: `require('path/to/file.svg?external')`.

Here's the corresponding rule:

```
{test: /\.svg\?external$/, use: "file-loader!image-webpack-loader"},
```

It seems like webpack 2 does not include the `?` part anymore when `test`ing for a rule since only the first rule is being applied  to *all* my svgs after migrating.

Is there a way around this? Is there maybe a different strategy of how to apply different set of loaders for files of the same extension when `require`ing them?

PS: I'm aware that I could require the file like this: `require('!file-loader!image-webpack-loader!path/to/file.svg')` but my loaders are a bit more complex than this and I don't want to repeat their configuration all the time.

PSS: This doesn't seem to work either (it still only applies the first rule)

```
{test: /\.svg$/, use: "svg-inline-loader", exclude: /\?external/},
{test: /\.svg$/, use: "file-loader?!image-webpack-loader", include: /\?external/}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I recently attended a talk by webpack's Juho Vepsäläinen and found the answer in [this slide](https://presentations.survivejs.com/webpack-from-apprentice-to-journeyman/#/48):

```
{
  test: /.css$/,

  oneOf: [
    {
      resourceQuery: /inline/, // foo.css?inline
      use: 'url-loader',
    },
    {
      resourceQuery: /external/, // foo.css?external
      use: 'file-loader',
    },
  ],
}
```

[resourceQuery](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resourcequery) to the rescue!

Comment: I have the same issue. I want to use less-loader for `*.less` files by default and custom loader for `*.less?module` files. But i don't want to add anything like `?default` to all '.less' files. Can you share your config?

Comment: `oneOf` uses the first matching rule. So for your use case put the `resourceQuery: /module/ ` into the first entry and no `resourceQuery` at all into the second.

Comment: @Daniel the life saver!

Answer (score 9):

[`resolveLoader.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) will be solution for you.

Your config will look like this:

```js
resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
    myLoader1: "svg-inline-loader", // and much more
    myLoader2: "file-loader!image-webpack-loader" // and much more
  }
}
```

and usage:

```js
require('myLoader1!path/to/file1.svg');
require('myLoader2!path/to/file2.svg');
```

---

Or if you want for example myLoader1 config to be default and from time to time use myLoader2 loaders use this kind of config:

```js
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: "svg-inline-loader" // and much more
}

// ...

resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
    myLoader: "file-loader!image-webpack-loader" // and much more
  }
}
```

and use like this:

```js
require('path/to/file1.svg'); // default svg-inline-loader
require('!myLoader!path/to/file2.svg'); // specific file-loader!image-webpack-loader
// ! at the beginning - disables loaders from default
// and myLoader enables file-loader and image-webpack-loader
```

PS. I had similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868655/specify-loader-configuration-from-webpack-config-file-in-request) it's for webpack 1 but documentation says that `resolveLoader.alias` works the same.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Yes this is looking very very helpful indeed :)

Comment: It seems like loader chaining isn't supported though: `require('!myLoader!path/to/file2.svg');` results in `./file-1234.svg!image-webpack-loader`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure out how to disable default loaders... spent a lot of time, not in vein, but nevertheless... a simple exclamation mark at the beginning of the path... lol

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `test`, you can specify `include`/`exclude` conditions. From the [docs on configuration options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options):

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
    ],
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app/demo-files")
    ]
    // these are matching conditions, each accepting a regular expression or string
    // test and include have the same behavior, both must be matched
    // exclude must not be matched (takes preferrence over test and include)
    // Best practices:
    // - Use RegExp only in test and for filename matching
    // - Use arrays of absolute paths in include and exclude
    // - Try to avoid exclude and prefer include
}
```

Comment: I just tried, and was not lucky. I updated my answer to show what I've did.