# Use different loaders for files with same extension

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, css-loader

I want to be able to use two different loaders for `'*.less'` files. 
Default one for all, but other for `'*.less?module'` files.
In webpack 1.x it was possible through:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$|\.css$/,
                use: ...
            },
            {
                test: /\.less\?module$/,
                use: ...
            },
```

How to do it in webpack 2 or 3?

Comment: Here's the relative question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074224/webpack-2-how-to-apply-different-loaders-for-files-with-same-extension)

Comment: but I don't want to write `?default` for all files that are not `?module`