# What webpack4 loader is used to load *.svg files, *.gif, *.eot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing a react UI component and it depends on another UI component (react-widgets/lib/DropDownlist).  This javascript module has resources that end with these file extensions: *.gif, *.eot, *.svg, *.woff, *.ttf.

Webpack4 is complaining that it doesn't know how to process these file types and that I might need a loader to handle these file type.  One error is:

```
Error in .../react-widgets/dist/fonts/rw-widgets.svg?v=4.1.0
Module parse failed: ...
**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.**
```

So I need to update my webpack.config.js file with the appropriate loaders for those file types.  [My config is based off of this](https://github.com/markusenglund/react-npm-component-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js).  *Side Note: A 
shout out goes to [Mark England who wrote this article which does a fantastic job for how to create a reusable component](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-guide-to-building-a-react-component-for-npm-68f03b314753).*

The relevant snippet is:

```
// Snippet from Mark's code webpack.config.js
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
},
```

I know what the [syntax for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration) is to define the loaders but I don't know what loaders to use.   But this sample webpack config file didn't include support for these other file types.

**What have I done to try and solve the problem**

- I generally use create-react-app so I avoid this problem altogether. :-)  It, however, doesn't allow me to create react libraries for distribution (AFAIK).
- First I searched on the net ***webpack *.gif loader***.  Nothing useful.
- Next I searched for ***webpack loaders based on file type***.  This gave some good results that describe the [loader syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration), pointed me to some loaders [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) and how to use them, and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074224/webpack-2-how-to-apply-different-loaders-for-files-with-same-extension) that helps me realize the *.svg loader might be what I need to load svg files.

`{test: /\.svg$/, use: "svg-inline-loader"},`

So I might be able to use svg-inline-loader for the *.svg files.
I can repeat this approach for all of the file types.

**The next approach is to examine Create React App (CRA)**

I primarily develop in react, and look at the CRA webpack config files (because the create-react-app appears to stay leading edge on these topic).  So I can see the url-loader is used for images (based on what the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js` file is using).

Another one down...

**My question**

**Does webpack (or another website) have a table that lists the loaders available for given file types?**

For example, 
know good image loaders for the following file types are:

```
Webpack 4
*.gif, *.jpg => url-loader
*.svg => svg-inline-loader
*.eot => ???
```

I realize that because webpack is more of a plugin/loader architecture that it might not be *webpacks* place to have this list so another website might need to have it.

**When you need a loader what do you do?**
If there is no central place to look for this answer, then please share how you find loaders that are needed to solve your webpack file loading problem.

Comment: Did you try the `file-loader`? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: Webpack compiles code; you don't want to compile gifs or any other image files. So your problem is different. I'm not posting this an answer but only as a something to look at. I think you may need to use a 'noparse' directive for the DropDownList component.  A snippet that I use may be helpful may be not....
    loaders: [{
      Your loaders here
      }],
     noParse: /(DropDownlist)\.js$/
  } ... Some version of this, maybe is where you need to be. I do know Webpack should not be compiling the image files, so that's a thread to follow, a place to start. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on your workflow, how u want to load assets at run-time.

For eg, if u have lot of images, it might be a good idea to use a file-loader and place them directly inside the build directory.

The above approach will increase the GET calls and the bundled js file size will not be affeted

If u have less images/small size images then you can use url-loader which converts them into data-URL and put them inside your bundled js files.

The above approach will reduce the GET calls and will slightly increase the bundled js size.

If u want combination of both, then u can set a size limit and fallback loader(file-loader) on url-loader. What this will do is, the size of the dataURL will be calculated.If the size is grater than the limit, the file-loader will be used, which will place it in the build directory.

**How I use them**

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'images/',
          name: '[name][hash].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(svg)$/,
    exclude: /fonts/, /* dont want svg fonts from fonts folder to be included */
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        options: {
          noquotes: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    exclude: /images/,  /* dont want svg images from image folder to be included */
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'fonts/',
          name: '[name][hash].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Your solution worked.  I incorrectly thought that webpack only ```copied modules``` to the destination bundle, and did not parse them and did not need loaders for the files in the node_modules folder.  This was just plain wrong.  Once I referenced ```react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css```, I had to define a CSS loader and allow webpack to parse that file.  And because that file referenced other files, I had to provide loaders for those other file types as well.  Lesson learned is _sometimes_ webpack does need to parse/process/load files that are in the node_modules directory.